# SQL query to insert more than one value for same atribute

Tags: sql, database, html

I want to make a web page to update scores of some students. This page should have following features :
After opening the page it should start with all the roll numbers facing a box which is already filled with the previous scores. Now we can edit any score and put new score in the box we want and then after pressing 'Done' button, score of all the students should be updated using one query. Please someone write that query

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you make an attempt at writing the code yourself, and encounter an error, we can help you solve it. We will not write code for you from a blank slate.

Comment: Try posting some code you've already tried, this is a place for help, not to have others write your projects for you.

Comment: I'm not asking you to design the whole page just suggest a query to update a specific column of a multiple rows.

Comment: you might have some example php or html tags we are asking for that

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET score1 = value1
WHERE codition to specify a row;
```

`Table_name` in your database. After that write a `new score` value with their `column name` and also in the where condition write a condition which will specify your score row which you want to update.